# Is "" ( empty-string ) equivalent to boolean false or a false(y) value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

Please explain a little bit on this topic. I have went through some articles but I have not satisfied with their explanations.

Comment: [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Hey!, @Cid could you explain a little deeper

Comment: I have no idea how I could explain in a better way than the mdn docs. What part you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty string ("") returns **falsy**. An easy way to understand this is by using the logical AND operator

**The logical AND operator**

> If the first object is falsy, it returns that object

```js
console.log('' && 'hello') // falsy && 'hello' --> returns falsy empty string ('')
console.log('hi' && 'hello') // truthy && 'hello' --> returns 'hello'
```

1. In the first `console.log()` the empty string is a **falsy** value and so it returns the empty string.
2. In the second `console.log()` the non-empty string is a **truthy** value and so it returns the second string `hello`